# Google Cloud Firestore only query documents where timestamp is older than x

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking for the correct syntax to get a documentSnapshot of the documents where a timestamp field (`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`) is x days old.

As example: In my collection each document has the timestamp field "`createdAt`". I have a daily scheduled cloud function which gets and logs all documents where "`createdAt"` is older than 5 days.

Which syntax am I aiming for?

Answer (score 6):

You can filter the query with a comparison using a date object:

```
const date = new Date(Date.now() - x * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  // x days ago
collectionRef.where('createdAt', '<', date)
```

Comment: this will filter with a static date, but a mechanism for a dynamic "now" would be useful. For example if you want all documents older than "now", the "now" date is evolving (gaining 1 second every second). In that case you might want to have a timer but that would be quite wasteful.

Comment: @Ced I assume that your case is different - maybe you're subscribing to a collection on frontend? If that is the case, the solution would be upon each snapshot to filter out old records, and have a timer to check your records for old ones (or do filtering in a getter).